# Connecting Amazon S3 to existing Django project

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There is a need to introduce external storage for media files uploaded by users in Django project. This is why I consider using Amazon S3. The problem is that I am not sure how to manage already existing files. Did anyone have the experience of connecting existing Django project and relocating media storage + already uploaded files onto Amazon S3? What are the possible caveats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend that you use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to manage your django's uploaded files with S3.

For an existing django project, you will have to move your existing uploaded files using `s3` cli.

Comment: would there be any issues with integrity of data? Let's say , if it is FileField of a model, and you basically move already uploaded file to an external storage - will it work ?

Comment: Yes it will work, Django's `FileField` only store the relative path, not the absolute one. You just have to make sure that your folder tree in s3 is the same as your current one.